# Where to learn about enemy game algorithms (like Starcraft/Warcraft)?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, starcraftgym

I would like to learn about games (strategy) algorithms especially about how do 
enemies algorithms works ?

Is there any good place for beginners?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many aspects for AI in strategy games, but keep in mind that there is a big difference between Realistic AI and AI that makes a game fun to play. Cheat where you can while not making it obvious to the player that the enemy is cheating.

AI Game Programming Wisdom books
http://www.aiwisdom.com/

- [AI Game Programming Wisdom](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584500778)
- [AI Game Programming Wisdom 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584502894)
- [AI Game Programming Wisdom 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584504579)
- [AI Game Programming Wisdom 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584505230)

Also gamedev.net has a huge collection on AI articles and a good forum with lots of information. (http://www.gamedev.net)

Game Programming Gems feature a section on AI as well, but when AI is what you want, go with the AI Game Programming Wisdom books.

Here is an overview on RTS specific articles: http://www.aiwisdom.com/ai_genrerts.html
Also look at Pathfinding, possibly some neural networks / genetic algorithms when you want to play with that, although it might be a bit overkill when you're just starting out.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to learn about AI. Secondly it comes down to designing an algorithm that has the computer compete against a human player (it has goals and actions to complete the goals)

[This may be a good start.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652449/self-learning-game-artificial-intelligence/1652455#1652455)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that's quite the question.

I'd start with the O'Reilly book, '[AI for Game Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005555)'.

Also explore the [Game Programming](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=field-keywords=game+programming) section on Amazon.com. There's a *lot* out there on strategic computation, game theory, random responses, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For beginners, I'd really recommend Mat Buckland's [Programming Game AI by Example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Game-Example-Mat-Buckland/dp/1556220782/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1263302332&sr=8-1)

It is very easy to follow and I've found that it provides an excellent starting point for Games AI.

However, as the posters above have previously said, the field of game AI is incredibly broad and more and more academic AI techniques are being introduced as the hardware advances. The AI Game Programming Wisdom books are very, very good, detailing techniques from various real world examples.

Answer (score 1):

For beginners [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/) is a great place to start.  It provides many on-line courses for free. The [Algorithms](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs215/CourseRev/1) and [Introduction to AI](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs271/CourseRev/1) courses may be particularly useful in this case.

Once you have a basic understanding of algorithms and AI you can move to more advanced resources.